# Error bars only plotting on one set of bars in geom_bar and geom_errorbar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
structure(list(type = c("aerial", "aerial", "aerial", "aerial", 
"TLAcmeth", "TLAcmeth", "TLAcmeth", "TLAcmeth", "TLAmeandaily", 
"TLAmeandaily", "TLAmeandaily", "TLAmeandaily"), season = c("Fall", 
"Spring", "Summer", "Winter", "Fall", "Spring", "Summer", "Winter", 
"Fall", "Spring", "Summer", "Winter"), TotalEffort = c(190673.543181818, 
218904.879166667, 203450.11969697, 56238.5424242424, 268342.820454545, 
285751.855555556, 345593.292424242, 98186.1393939394, 231709.359979371, 
240226.110903571, 297768.291682299, 89965.0324616366), TotalVariance = c(492915253.434218, 
568040077.261171, 647316950.988574, 98882407.0742865, 1809446616.57252, 
1459917672.26073, 2412306298.47967, 249200347.968292, 690088788.630394, 
219887023.857297, 762532238.93411, 184763903.639171), STE = c(22201.6948324721, 
23833.5913630567, 25442.424235685, 9943.96334839819, 42537.5906296128, 
38208.8690261924, 49115.2348918304, 15786.0808299049, 26269.5410814577, 
14828.588060139, 27613.9862919882, 13592.7886630806)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```

When I go to plot these data using this ggplot code:

```
ggplot(E_StE, aes(x = season, y = TotalEffort, fill = type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Estimated Effort (h)", expand = c(0, 0)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = TotalEffort-STE, ymax = TotalEffort+STE), position = "dodge", width = 0.2) +
  xlab("Season")
```

I get this output:

[image]

What is wrong with my code where I all of my error bars are on one bar not their assigned bar?

Comment: change `position = "dodge"` to `position = position_dodge(0.9)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you changed the width of the error bars. If you take the width out you get

```
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = TotalEffort-STE, ymax = TotalEffort+STE),
   position ="dodge")
```

[image]
Sp you can set the width of the dodging to be different than the width of the bars:

```
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = TotalEffort-STE, ymax = TotalEffort+STE), 
   position = position_dodge(width=.9), width=.2)
```

[image]